# Install by command line

Tags: sql-server, installation, command-line, setup

I am using following command line to install `SQL Server 2008 R2` but its not installing. Also, I am not getting any error or log in `summary.txt`.

> `"D:\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU (1).exe" /q /ACTION= Install /FEATURES=SQL`
>   `/INSTANCENAME=nvt /SECURITYMODE=SQL /sapwd=abc`
>   `/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`

Comment: Well, If the above is a copy paste from what you are using, I suspect you may have had a few syntactical errors.  Firstly, remove the space between the "=" and "Install".  Also "IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS" has no spaces.

Comment: You can also add the /INDICATEPROGRESS parameter to pipe a verbose log to the console.

Comment: how to pipe a verbose log to the console?

Comment: Hi. You would need to add the `/INDICATEPROGRESS` parameter to your command line. If you would like to add all the console contents to a text file, you could add  `"> yourtextfile.txt"` to the end of your command line too.  You may have to specify a file location to save the text file, for e.g. `"> c:\temp\sqlinstlog.txt"`.

Comment: For e.g. your command line will become 
`"D:\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU (1).exe" /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=nvt /SECURITYMODE=SQL /sapwd=abc /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS >c:\temp\log.txt"`.

Comment: I just had another thought... when you specify the SA password in the `/SAPWD` switch, you may have to ensure that you enter a password that complies to the server's local security policy complexity settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [blog](http://mssqltrek.com/2011/08/23/installing-sql-server-from-command-linecmd/), and the solution the author described works like a charm for me.

Below is command line install command

```
setup.exe /QUIETSIMPLE /ACTION=install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQL2008 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT=”NT Authority\System” /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”sreekanthpc\sreekanth”
/AGTSVCACCOUNT=”NT Authority\System” /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=”Pa$$w0rd” 
/SQLTEMPDBDIR=”D:\SQL2008\TempDB\\” /SQLUSERDBDIR=”D:\SQL2008\SQLData\\” 
/SQLUSERDBLOGDIR=”D:\SQL2008\SQLLog\\”
```

I hope this helps